# 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable' about lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror

what does this error mean?

this is my code:

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

averages = list()
sorted_averages = list()
dic = dict()
with open('first.csv') as fopen:
    reader = csv.reader(fopen)
    for line in reader:
        name = line[0]
        line = line[1:]
        counter = 0
        for i in line:
            i = float(i)
            line[counter] = i
            counter += 1
        average = mean(line)
        averages.append(average)
        dic[name] = average
    for i in range(0, len(averages)):
        maxi = 0
        maxi1 = 0
        for number in averages:
            if number > maxi:
                maxi = number
            elif number == maxi:
                maxi = number
                maxi1 = number
            else:
                maxi = maxi
        sorted_averages.append(maxi)
        averages.remove(maxi)
    del(averages)
    insorted_averages = sorted_averages.reverse()
    for z in insorted_averages[:3]:
        print(z)
```

i have sorted my list from max to min. Now i want to print 3 worth averages but i got that error. i have done with with changing 3 to -4 but it didnt work too

Comment: Hi, can you please post your full traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.reverse()` reverses your list in-place and returns `None`:

```
sorted_averages = list(range(3))
insorted_averages = sorted_averages.reverse()
print(insorted_averages)
```

`insorted_averages` is now `None`. `sorted_averages` is reversed though...

read (4) in the python doc under [mutable sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mutable-sequence-types).